# Android version of nanosleep?

Tags: java, android

Is there a version of C's nanosleep that exists within Java/Android? I'm attempting to send some commands from Android over serial and I'd like to sleep for a very small amount of time after each command is send over the port.

Comment: This should be interesting to you http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/10/measuring-microsecond-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java the concept of timing is vague, and the smaller the delay you want to sleep, the less likely you are to get an accurate result.

If you really want short delays, then ['yielding'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) for a moment may be enough:

```
Thread.yield();
```

Other forms of [Thread.sleep(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long,%20int%29) may sleep for longer, or shorter, than you request.... depending on the granularity of your system.....

Even looping on a short sleep is error-prone.

If your delay is less than a millisecond, I would be tempted to do a spin-loop, otherwise I would just set a delay and hope it's close enough.